# JavaScript Replace not replacing second <

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, visual-studio, xss

I am trying to replace < and > signs of HTML tags with `&gt;` & `&lt;` using JavaScript. I am using following code:

```
var sval = val.replace('&', '&amp;');
sval = sval.replace("<", "&lt;");
sval = sval.replace(">", "&gt;");
```

But it's replacing only first occurrence of <. Following is the snapshot of the values at the breakpoint:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using regular expressions:

```
var sval = val.replace(/&/g, '&amp;');
sval = sval.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
sval = sval.replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
```

The `g` flag (=global) tells the replace function to not stop after the first hit.

Answer (score 2):

Use `g` as third parameter to remove all occurance

```
var sval = val.replace('&', '&amp;','g')
              .replace("<", "&lt;",'g')
              .replace(">", "&gt;",'g');
// g represents global match
```

[Documentation : **replace()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 1):

```
    var sval = val.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
```